# Change image onclick using javascript

Tags: javascript, image, dom, onclick

Here's my problem:

I am new to Javascript and I am trying to make my image change on click.

It's a simple counter game that does a 2 frame animation of squidward hitting the dab.

So far I have got the counter to work but I cannot get the image to change on click as well. Also, it's going to have to change back to the original image so that it can be clicked and counted again.

```
  <html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
 <body>
<div class="container">

        <button onclick="dabMan()"><img src="./squid-dab1.gif"> . 
        </button>
        <br><br>
        How many dabs??
        <input type="text" id="text">

</div>


<script src="./script.js"></script>


  </body>
 </html>

var dabcount = 0;

function dabMan() {
dabcount = dabcount + 1
document.getElementById('text').value = dabcount;
console.log("dabMan", dabMan)

document.getElementById("./squid-dab1.gif") .src = "./squid-dab2.gif";
console.log("changeimage", dabMan)
 }
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("./squid-dab1.gif")` You have no such `id` in the document

Comment: Agree with @CertainPerformance you need to call an ID and not an image path in your document.getElementById calls.

Comment: Your `img` element has the `src` attribute of `./squid-dab1.gif` but does not have an `id` so using `document.getElementById("./squid-dab1.gif")` will not target that element if that is your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using the "onclick(){}" attribute in your html, write an event listener in js. Assuming your image tag is like this:

```
<img src='./squid-dab1.gif' id='myImage'>
```

**Note:** Javascript needs to know how to find your image... Hence the ID

Your javascript code should look like this:

```
<script>
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

    image.addEventListener('click', function(){
        changeImage();
    });

    function changeImage(){
        image.src = './squid-dab2.gif';
    }
</script>
```

That will make it so that when you click the image, it will change. If you wanted a button to do that, simply create a button with the id "myImage" instead like so:

```
<button id='myImage'>Click me to change the picture</button>
```

Comment: No problem! Event listeners are great and once you get the hang of Vanilla Javascript, start looking into jQuery to make your life a lot easier with events.